# How to make 2nd Trigger script in paired image button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Set A is a scripted paired button image. When you click certain image, it will change to its pair or set of image.

Now If I have another set, Set B, and I want to make set B to work exactly like set A without disrupting each other. How to do this? I tried to give set B new unique ID but confused how to integrate the new ID in the script.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').click(function() {
    $(this).add($(this).siblings()).toggleClass('hide');
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'predator_only') {
      $('.predator:not(.hide)').add($('.predator:not(.hide)').siblings()).toggleClass('hide');
    }
    else if($(this).attr('id') == 'mixed') {
      $('.predator.hide').add($('.predator.hide').siblings()).toggleClass('hide');
    }
    else
    {
      if($('.predator.hide').length > 0) {
        $('#mixed').removeClass('hide');
        $('#predator_only').addClass('hide');
      }
      else {
        $('#mixed').addClass('hide');
        $('#predator_only').removeClass('hide');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* For layout only */
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Used to hide image */
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

This is set A:
<div>
<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/3tsfw9psl/Predator.png" id="predator_only"/>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/nn4joz36d/Mixed.png" class="hide" id="mixed"/>
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/ski4a355h/Lion.png" class="predator" />
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/s2myu8fkl/Deer.png" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/vxvetx51x/Wolf.png" class="predator"/>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/ty9r5e4et/Lamb.png" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/ll42aq579/Tiger.png" class="predator"/>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/f11a4dr6d/Goat.png" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/flgb72ket/Shark.png" class="predator"/>
  <img src="https://s4.postimg.org/rk8v1dv9p/Seal.png" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/wn9595z9x/Cheetah.png" class="predator"/>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/h4bpc1qz9/Gazelle.png" class="hide" />
</div>
</div>

<br><br>
This is set B:
<div>
<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/3tsfw9psl/Predator.png" id="predator_only2"/>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/nn4joz36d/Mixed.png" class="hide" id="mixed2"/>
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/ski4a355h/Lion.png" class="predator2" />
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/s2myu8fkl/Deer.png" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/vxvetx51x/Wolf.png" class="predator2"/>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/ty9r5e4et/Lamb.png" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/ll42aq579/Tiger.png" class="predator2"/>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/f11a4dr6d/Goat.png" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/flgb72ket/Shark.png" class="predator2"/>
  <img src="https://s4.postimg.org/rk8v1dv9p/Seal.png" class="hide" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/wn9595z9x/Cheetah.png" class="predator2"/>
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/h4bpc1qz9/Gazelle.png" class="hide" />
</div>
</div>
```